# Why does having scanf & printf in a loop cause this output

Tags: c, loops, printf, scanf

The program in question:
**#1:**

```c
int main(void) {
  int size;
  scanf("%d", &size);
  int v[size];
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      scanf("%d", &v[i]);
      printf("the %d-th element is : %d\n",i, v[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

O/P:

```
5
6 7 8 9 10 11
the 0-th element is : 6
the 1-th element is : 7
the 2-th element is : 8
the 3-th element is : 9
the 4-th element is : 10
```

**My question:** *Why does it seem like the program does all the print statements after your input?*

So does the program kind of 'hold' the print statements to display them after you press `<Enter>` for a new-line? Is there a better explanation of this behavior somewhere?

**Edit after @dbush's answer**
I need a bit of a clarity on this: so let's say the `size = 5` & my input is `6 7 8 9 10` so I'm asuming the first `scanf` in the loop reads the `6 ` part then reads/stores the data and then <s>passes the rest of the content that's in the input buffer to the next `scanf`'s</s> leaves the rest of the input data in the `input buffer`

Then the program goes towards the printf statement stores that output in some sort of a buffer then it loops back to the 2-nd scanf and that reads the `7`  part and all of this goes till the `10<enter>` part, now the final scanf reads/stores `11` and since there's a newline, the programs decides that it no longer needs to read from the `input buffer` and now outputs the rest of the contents from the `output buffer` to the console.

Is this how it goes or are there some inaccuraries in this analogy?

**Edit #2:** I found this [good blogpost](https://zakuarbor.github.io/blog/a-look-at-input-buffer-using-scanf/) explaining what goes on with `scanf`'s & the input buffer, together with @dbush & @Weather Vane answers to completely answer any doubts I've had regarding this

Comment: You ask for 5 array values but supplied 6. The extra value was ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading from a terminal, nothing gets sent to `scanf` until you press ENTER.

So in your case, you have 6 strings which look like numbers in the input buffer.  The first `scanf` reads just the first number, because that's what its pattern is looking for and leaves the rest in the input buffer.  Then the program continues by calling `printf`, and because the string ends with a newline it gets printed immediately.  When the program then loops back around to `scanf`, there's already data in the input buffer so it reads what's there and returns immediately, and the cycle continues.

So only the first call to `scanf` is waiting for input from the user, while the others are reading what's already in the input buffer, and the `printf` calls are having their output go to the terminal immediately since the string to print ends with a newline.

Comment: I'd say it's one string with one number in it, then `<enter>`, then `scanf()` reads the number, then another string with *five* numbers in it, then `<enter>`, then the loop runs.  IMO that's closer to what the program reads in this case.

Comment: @AndrewHenle @dbush I've another doubt related to how the program is interpreting my input with the `scanf`'s. Can you view the edit of my question for that? (a bit long to add it in the reply section)

Comment: @dbush I did, can you see my edit to my post as well? Just so you can check if my understanding is a correct interpretation of yours

Comment: @3rdgrade-dropout It doesn't so much "pass" the content to the next `scanf` as it does just leave the data in the buffer for the next `scanf` to pick up, and the `printf` output isn't being buffered.

Comment: @dbush so there isn't an `output  buffer`?  So how are these print statements 'stored' to display them all at once after the newline?

Comment: The output lines aren't stored. Nothing even happens until you press Enter to complete the input, and then *all* the inputs are ready and waiting, so the outputs are printed immediately.

Comment: @dbush @WeatherVane I get it now thank you so much. `Nothing happens till you press Enter` clicked it to me. You see I was thinking the program was sort of doing the scanfs whilst I was giving the input (which is stupidly wrong in hindsight)